# Connect iPhone to wifi

Tags: iphone, wireless-networking, connection

In the iphone settings I have wifi turned on. It even detects the wifi, I have entered the password.

When I open any app, I get a "not connected to internet"

Its kind of funny, I know its got to be easy to figure, but I am trying to connect my iphone to wifi unsuccessfully for the past 15 min.

What setting changes should I do, to have it connect automatically (I have done that in the settings)

Comment: Is it jailbroken?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to delete your saved info about your router.

Go to Settings->Wi-Fi-> select the right arrow next to the name of your router-> Select "Forget this Network".

Now try to connect to the router again.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of network are you trying to connect to?  There could be security measures in place that prevent connection like hotspots with auto-redirected login pages and such. Does the Wifi icon show active signal strength? Is their mac address authentication security policies in place?

Comment: Its my own home wifi. I have entered the password too.

Comment: What kind of security (WEP, WPA, WPA2) do you have set on the router?